# Simple Starvation Program that throws exception

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written three starvation program but none of them throws the exception as :

```
"Thread-2" prio=1 tid=0x080db6c8 nid=0x22de waiting for monitor entry [0xa81e4000..0xa81e4150]
      at yourClass.run(yourcCass.java:55)
      - waiting to lock <0xa89fc7f0> (a java.lang.Object)
      - locked <0xa89fcdb0> (a starvation)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

"Thread-1" prio=1 tid=0x080da780 nid=0x22dd waiting for monitor entry [0xa8264000..0xa82650d0]
      at yourClass.run(yourClass.java:55)
      - waiting to lock <0xa89fc7f0> (a java.lang.Object)
      - locked <0xa89fcc48> (a starvation)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

"Thread-0" prio=1 tid=0x080d9100 nid=0x22db in Object.wait() [0xa8366000..0xa8366fd0]
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      - waiting on <0xa89fc978> (a starvation)
      at starvation.run(yourClass.java:62)
      - locked <0xa89fc7f0> (a java.lang.Object)
      - locked <0xa89fc978> (a starvation)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

that shows your program is in starvation.

Can anybody help with simple Starvation program that throws above exception.

With the help provided The code I wrote is :

```
public class ThreadStarvation implements Runnable{

boolean t1Entered = false;

public synchronized void synchronizedTimerMethod(){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" enters synchronized block");
    while (!t1Entered && !Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t1")) { 
        try {
            wait();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    t1Entered = true;

    while (true) {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" in synchronized block");

    }
}

public void run(){
    synchronizedTimerMethod();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadStarvation ts1=new ThreadStarvation();

    Thread t1=new Thread(ts1);
    t1.setName("t1");

    Thread t2=new Thread(ts1);
    t2.setName("t2");

    t2.start();

    try{
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

    t1.start();

    try{
        Thread.sleep(16000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
    System.out.println(t1.getState());
    System.out.println(t2.getState());

  }
}
```

t2 will be in starvation then why no message is given by JVM that t2 is in starvation or waiting for monitor entry? I allowed my program to run for 20 mins.

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: SO helps those who help themselves... what do you have so far?

Comment: what exception do you expect? Why do you think starvation relates to an exception?

Comment: @barakmanos Provided the code

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov some kind of message should be given when after a long time resource is not available to thread.

Comment: @dcsohl Provided the code

Comment: @Nizam: from where do you draw the conclusion that there *should* be a message? The program does exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: I believe you are not fully aware of which thread is which. I recommend you split your code in at least 2 classes. One is the `ThreadStarvation implements Runnable`. The other is some kind of TestSetup Class that has the `main` method. That might help you to understand the scope of the variables used.

Comment: I think another source of confusion is that the block at the top is not an exception message. That's a thread-dump. Java does not auto-detect starvation or deadlocks and provide helpful exceptions, more's the pity.

Comment: I read a sample program on starvation which throws messages shown above. I will share you the link. Frankly speaking I have not understood the program code of provided link clearly, so I was asking for the simple program.

Comment: link :- [http://www.lrdev.com/lr/java/starvation.java](http://www.lrdev.com/lr/java/starvation.java)

Answer (score 0):

jvm doesn't throw an exception for starvation itself. The thread will keep waiting for a monitor.

You can use lock.trylocak and throw an exception if a thread can't get a lock after a few retries.

Comment: **lock.trylocak** what is that? can you explain briefly?

Comment: pardon my spelling mistake, its lock.tryLock, here is an example for the same http://robaustin.wikidot.com/reentrantlock .Basically the idea is that you can specify a timeout for which you will try the lock and do something else if you don not get the lock.